# Re-enable RadButton with property SingleClick=true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Upon clicking **btnSearch**, it disables it with telerik's **SingleClick=true** property. If validation fails it doesn't postback and I try
to set the button back to being enabled but it doesn't get set. It still is disabled with the text saying **"Searching..."**.

What I am trying to do is if it fails the validation, I want 
the button to be enabled again. Right now if i click on it and validation fails, it gets stuck being disabled.

javascript

```
function Validate(button, args) {
     if (error) {
                    button.set_autoPostBack(true);
                }
                else { //validation fails
                    button.set_autoPostBack(false);
                    button.set_enabled(true); // i have currently
                }
    }
```

aspx

```
 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSearch"  Text="Search" SingleClick="true" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClicking="Validate" SingleClickText="Searching..." ></telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling the **enableAfterSingleClick()** method of the RadButton to enable it again.

Link to the client-side docs of RadButton: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-client-side-basics.html